# React Hook Form - validation on inverse of regular expression

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

When using React Hook Forms, I can provide a pattern attribute when validating the content of an input.

But let's say that I want to sanitize the input and make sure that there are no HTML tags in it and display an error if there are.

```
<input
    type="text"
    {...register('myInput', {
        required: true,
        pattern: /some regex for validating if a string contains HTML tags/
    })}
/>
```

Let's imagine that this Regex is already written and has worked for many years. However, what I want is the inverse of this Regex to be applied. Otherwise, React Hook Form will *only* want HTML tags in the input and not disallow it.

Is there a way to make React Hook Forms validate against the inverse of a pattern match?

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out myself. Instead of using the `pattern` property, I used `validate` instead like so:

```
<input
    type="text"
    {...register('myInput', {
        required: true,
        validate: value => value.match(/my-regex/) == null || 'error message'
    })}
/>
```